# How should I process XML with PHP?

Tags: php, httprequest

I'm trying to collect XML from multiple devices and run them through a PHP server. Could someone walk me through how to create a server, send the data (via curl), accept the data with PHP, then parse it for a database?

Comment: For a server to handle http requests you would need to have a web server installed. If you put an XML file in your web server directory then the request would output the XML file...

Comment: i have apache running on my pc , if thats what you mean. i ve written php before but never to handle this

Comment: -1 this is equivalent to "how can I upload a file" or event "how does php work" - the fact that your'e submitting the request from a mobile device isn't particularly relevant - the server receivers a post request - which contains xml or an xml file attachment - you process it and send a response. Show something specific if you want specific help.

Comment: how can i process the http request is my question. The get/post is to send an xml. But this is for the sender. I need to understand how i can make the receiver get the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a quick VPS server, I would recommend using EC2.

Then, make a LAMP server, this is a really easy guide to follow. http://www.lamphowto.com

You need to make sure you have Apache running, because that is what is answering and serving the http requests, not PHP. PHP is just another language downstream that manipulates the response.

**Edit:
For future viewers, the OP and I discussed this further, he was actually wondering how to parse the XML. I referenced this link: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5**

Comment: how will apache answer them? i have apache on my pc running.

Comment: @donparalias Firstly, you probably don't want to do it on a local computer, unless this is only for you personally. When you send a request to a server that has been properly configured (read my guide), it should respond with the corresponding file that was requested. I assume you haven't configured it yet?

Comment: ok ok i dont know why my question is so confusing. I am working on a project on my own. i have apache/mysql/php on my pc with xampp. I am just making this localy to test it and then of course i ll go with the server. everything i write in php works on my server ok. I just dont know how to do this. so apache will automatically handle it? you dont need code to do this? I need it to respond to the xml file save it in the database etc etc. But at first to get it. What do you mean configure?

Comment: @donparalias I still don't understand what you are asking - Your PHP works, you have XAMPP up, which means Apache is installed. Are you now asking how to write PHP code to save XML to a database?

Comment: Now i have the server running. If i send the xml file to my server ip , from my mobile phone ,  will apache handle the file alone? It doesnt need any php coding for it?

Comment: @donparalias send the XML as a POST Request to the server, then on the PHP side use $_POST['xml'] to get the content.

Comment: i think thats what i was looking for. So lets say i have a php file called receiver.php. I must send the xml file to this exact location like my.ip.is.that/receiver.php  and in this file i will handle it as you said? and if there are many multiple http requests they will all be handled? Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: @donparalias Yes / Yes / Yes

Comment: Thanks man that was exactly what i wanted :) In order to find a tutorial with some code on it how can i search the google for this? For the http post/get request to send the xml file there are tons of stuff on google , but for this how do you call it? "handling http requests with xml" ?  i didnt even know how to make the question..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22648/discussion-between-donparalias-and-jonathan)